# Finished execution of CiviCRM Update Check with result: Failure, Error message: DB Error: no such table

Tags: upgrade

The error in the title appears in the Civicrm System Status after upgrade to 5.57.1

As far as I can get, it does not manage to check for the existence of new civicrm versions, so it should not be anything too serious...

This is the detail from the log entry:

```
Parameters parsed (and passed to API method): 
a:1:{s:7:"version";i:3;}

Full message: 
Finished execution of CiviCRM Update Check with result: Failure, Error message: DB Error: no such table
```

Looking under Administer > Administration Console > View Log I can understand what is the missing table. I see two entries:

```
[debug] $backTrace = #0 /home/usiako1s/domains/figg.org/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(954): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE)
```

and

```
[error] $Fatal Error Details = Array
```

Here is the detail from the first one:

```
 [debug] $backTrace = #0 /home/usiako1s/domains/figg.org/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(954): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE)
#1  administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(921): CRM_Core_Error::exceptionHandler(Object(DB_Error))
#2  administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB.php(997): PEAR_Error->__construct("DB Error: no such table", -18, 16, (Array:2), "SELECT count(`civicrm_grant`.`id`) as `DATAOBJECT_NUM`\n                FROM ...")
#3  administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(575): DB_Error->__construct(-18, 16, (Array:2), "SELECT count(`civicrm_grant`.`id`) as `DATAOBJECT_NUM`\n                FROM ...")
#4  administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(223): PEAR::_raiseError(Object(DB_mysqli), NULL, -18, 16, (Array:2), "SELECT count(`civicrm_grant`.`id`) as `DATAOBJECT_NUM`\n                FROM ...", "DB_Error", TRUE)
#5  administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1925): PEAR->__call("raiseError", (Array:7))
#6  administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/mysqli.php(936): DB_common->raiseError(-18, NULL, NULL, "SELECT count(`civicrm_grant`.`id`) as `DATAOBJECT_NUM`\n                FROM ...", "1146 ** Table 'usiako1s_figg.civicrm_grant' doesn't exist")
#7  administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/mysqli.php(406): DB_mysqli->mysqliRaiseError()
#8  administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1231): DB_mysqli->simpleQuery("SELECT count(`civicrm_grant`.`id`) as `DATAOBJECT_NUM`\n                FROM ...")
#9  administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(2696): DB_common->query("SELECT count(`civicrm_grant`.`id`) as `DATAOBJECT_NUM`\n                FROM ...")
#10 administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(1803): DB_DataObject->_query("SELECT count(`civicrm_grant`.`id`) as `DATAOBJECT_NUM`\n                FROM ...")
#11 administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/VersionCheck.php(218): DB_DataObject->count()
#12 administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/VersionCheck.php(153): CRM_Utils_VersionCheck->getEntityStats()
#13 administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/VersionCheck.php(125): CRM_Utils_VersionCheck->getSiteStats()
#14 administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/api/v3/Job.php(751): CRM_Utils_VersionCheck->fetch()
#15 administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/Civi/API/Provider/MagicFunctionProvider.php(89): civicrm_api3_job_version_check((Array:1))
#16 administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/Civi/API/Kernel.php(158): Civi\API\Provider\MagicFunctionProvider->invoke((Array:8))
#17 administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/Civi/API/Kernel.php(81): Civi\API\Kernel->runRequest((Array:8))
#18 administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/api/api.php(22): Civi\API\Kernel->runSafe("Job", "version_check", (Array:1))
#19 administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/JobManager.php(131): civicrm_api("Job", "version_check", (Array:1))
#20 administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/JobManager.php(63): CRM_Core_JobManager->executeJob(Object(CRM_Core_ScheduledJob))
#21 administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bin/cron.php(26): CRM_Core_JobManager->execute()
#22 {main}
```

and here is the detail from the second one:

```
 [error] $Fatal Error Details = Array
(
    [callback] => Array
        (
            [0] => CRM_Core_Error
            [1] => exceptionHandler
        )

    [code] => -18
    [message] => DB Error: no such table
    [mode] => 16
    [debug_info] => SELECT count(`civicrm_grant`.`id`) as `DATAOBJECT_NUM`
                FROM `civicrm_grant`   [nativecode=1146 ** Table 'usiako1s_figg.civicrm_grant' doesn't exist]
    [type] => DB_Error
    [user_info] => SELECT count(`civicrm_grant`.`id`) as `DATAOBJECT_NUM`
                FROM `civicrm_grant`   [nativecode=1146 ** Table 'usiako1s_figg.civicrm_grant' doesn't exist]
    [to_string] => [db_error: message="DB Error: no such table" code=-18 mode=callback callback=CRM_Core_Error::exceptionHandler prefix="" info="SELECT count(`civicrm_grant`.`id`) as `DATAOBJECT_NUM`
                FROM `civicrm_grant`   [nativecode=1146 ** Table 'usiako1s_figg.civicrm_grant' doesn't exist]"]
)
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue. If you check your log file, it should pinpoint the missing table. The log file for me is visible under Administer > Administration Console > View Log. I'm missing the civicrm_grant table; unsure at this point how to restore it.

Comment: Mh, no. I edited the question to show what I see in the logs.

Comment: If you click on the number next to the log entry, that gives you more detail about the error.

Comment: Thanks. I added this detail

Comment: Looks like we're missing the same civicrm_grant table - so hopefully someone chimes in with a fix! I've snoozed the error message for now for the next 30 days, because we've had the issue for a while and the only problem it causes is that you don't get pinged for updates.

Answer (score 2):

Are you actually using civigrant? I guess not if you don't even have that table. So try disabling the civigrant extension then re-enabling. If that doesn't help then uninstall the extension and re-install it.

Comment: I do not use civigrant, so I had uninstalled it. After installing and disabling it, the error has disappeared. Thanks!